# why when i float something to left in css, i cant overwrite one of the item to right

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#wrap{
      border: 1px solid black;
      width: 500px;
      height: 200px;
}

#wrap div{
     border: 1px solid red;
     width: 100px;
     height: 150px;
     float: left;
}

.item2{
   float: right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="item1"></div>
    <div class="item2"></div>
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

Why my div item 2 did not flow right?Anyone can help me with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of [CSS precedence](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/).

Change your selector to:

```
#wrap .item2{
   float: right;
}
```

[See Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uXs9h/)

Comment: @dramasea Yes, because of CSS precedence. See my link in the question. http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

Comment: @dramasea `#wrap div` takes priority over `.item2`

Comment: thx, is there anymore css formart that normally we don't know?

Comment: @dramasea I don't know, thats quite a generic question. It depends on your experience, and how you have learnt.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing an issue with CSS specificity.

There's a great article here:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

However, try the following:

```
<style>
#wrap{
      border: 1px solid black;
      width: 500px;
      height: 200px;
}

#wrap div{
     border: 1px solid red;
     width: 100px;
     height: 150px;
     float: left;
}

#wrap .item2{
   float: right;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#wrap div.item2{float: right;}
```

Answer (score -1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tgqNF/)

Try this:

```
.item2{
   float: right !important;
}
```

Comment: Why would you ever want to use `!important`?

Comment: See the demo it works @Amberlamps
Why downvote? it works is another solution

Comment: I see that it works, but it is not an the ends justify the means kind of thing. If you style your mark up correctly, you will never have to use `!important`.

Comment: Ok but is a solution and if he don't wanto that float:left override right this is another solution isn't wrong. Isn't the best solution but isn't wrong! if you donwvote is for a code that doesn't work or is bad. If you don't like this solution or isn't the best ok don't vote up but not vote down if it works!

Comment: You already said it yourself: "if you downvote for a code [...] that is bad"

Comment: but the tag important isn't bad, I know that in the code you don't have to use it so much but in some case for not override is a solution. if you don't use it or isn't the best don't use it but isn't so bad for the code

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri I recommend you read this article: http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/ . If you don't believe this article is going to get any upvotes, and youre unhappy about your downvote, simply delete your answer.

Comment: @Curt I know when I have to use !important but in the title he says about 'overwrite' and the !important help to don't override. I know that your answer is better I wrote only another solution, isn't a problem of downvote

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri: Why would you ever write another solution, if you think that a different one is better? Please do not spread solutions that you don´t think is the best answer for the use case. This is not a discussion board.

Comment: is another way to solve the problem. Is the first thing that I have thinked because in the question he told about overwrite @Amberlamps

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri: It does not really matter, what your thinking process was. I personally think, that your solution is a bad idea. Some people would agree, some would disagree. But nonetheless I downvote this solution for the already posted reasons.